# How to remove the first set of zero-valued columns (or rows) in spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hello I am new to spark and I have two data frames such that:

```
+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|        Region| 3/7/20| 3/8/20| 3/9/20|3/10/20|3/11/20|3/12/20|3/13/20|
+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|         Paris|      0|      0|      0|      1|      7|      0|      5|
+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+----------+-------+
|    Period|Reports|
+----------+-------+
|2020/07/20|      0|
|2020/07/21|      0|
|2020/07/22|      0|
|2020/07/23|      8|
|2020/07/24|      0|
|2020/07/25|      1|
+----------+-------+
```

How to can I drop the first 0-valued consecutive column 3/7/20, 3/8/20, 3/9/20, without deleting the column 3/12/20 ?
Similarly for the second dataframe how to remove the rows 3/12/20, 0 and 2020/07/21, 0 and 2020/07/22, 0 without deleting the row with 2020/07/22, 0

Comment: I don't see the meaning or the link between the 2 dataframe. Is the second one actually used ?

Comment: @JoJolyne, `remove the rows 3/12/20, 0 and 2020/07/21, 0 and 2020/07/22, 0 without deleting the row with 2020/07/22, 0` should be renamed to `remove the rows 2020/17/20, 0 and 2020/07/21, 0 and 2020/07/22, 0 without deleting the row with 2020/07/24, 0` will be meaningful. and I have provided the solution for that, please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
val df=Seq(("0","0","0","1","7","0","5")).toDF("3/7/20","3/8/20","3/9/20","3/10/20","3/11/20","3/12/20","3/13/20") 

var columnsAndValues = df.columns.flatMap { c => Array(lit(c), col(c)) } 
df.printSchema() 
val df1 = df.withColumn("myMap", map(columnsAndValues:_*)).select(explode($"myMap"))
.toDF("Region","Paris")

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(lit("A")).orderBy(lit("A")) 

df1.withColumn("row_number",row_number.over(windowSpec))
.withColumn("lag", lag("Paris", 1, 0).over(windowSpec))
.withColumn("lead", lead("Paris", 1, 0)
.over(windowSpec)).where(($"lag">0) or ($"Paris"> 0)).show()

/*
+-------+-----+----------+---+----+                                             
| Region|Paris|row_number|lag|lead|
+-------+-----+----------+---+----+
|3/10/20|    1|         4|  0|   7|
|3/11/20|    7|         5|  1|   0|
|3/12/20|    0|         6|  7|   5|
|3/13/20|    5|         7|  0|   0|
+-------+-----+----------+---+----+
*/

val df2=Seq(("2020/07/20","0"),("2020/07/21","0"),("2020/07/22","0"),("2020/07/23","8"),("2020/07/24","0"),("2020/07/25","1")).toDF("Period","Reports")

df2.withColumn("row_number",row_number.over(windowSpec))
.withColumn("lag", lag("Reports", 1, 0).over(windowSpec))
.withColumn("lead", lead("Reports", 1, 0).over(windowSpec))
.where((($"lag">0) or ($"Reports"> 0)) and ($"row_number">1)).show()

/*
+----------+-------+----------+---+----+                                        
|    Period|Reports|row_number|lag|lead|
+----------+-------+----------+---+----+
|2020/07/23|      8|         4|  0|   0|
|2020/07/24|      0|         5|  8|   1|
|2020/07/25|      1|         6|  0|   0|
+----------+-------+----------+---+----+
*/
```